# How to prompt for input when stdin is occupied?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, stdin

In Bash, how can I ask for user input while I'm processing data from stdin? In this case, the `read` or `select` commands do not work. E.g.:

```
while read line
do
    # process line
    echo "Do you want to continue? [y/n]"
done
```

Comment: did you tried using [read](http://www.linuxnix.com/2012/05/7-linux-read-command-examples-shell-scripting.html) ?

Comment: `read -p "Do you want to continue? [y/n]" ans`

Comment: @Arvind Of course, but this doesn't work. In the example, the read command would return immediately without waiting for user input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps `read` with its *stdin* redirected from `/dev/tty` should help

Untested code (see [tty(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty.4.html) about `/dev/tty`):

```
read -p "Continue? [y/n]: " yn < /dev/tty
```